# Android Volley JSON Request display empty data in TextView

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I reading Android official docs and trying to display JSON data in `Textview`. I tried the following coding but when I click on the `Button`, nothing appears and also no error prompt. What's wrong with it? The coding is mainly from Android official docs.

```
TextView mTxtDisplay;

String url = "http://192.168.1.102/web_service/test.php/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
}}
```

**192.168.1.102/web_service/test.php**

```
{
"1":{"name":"Superman","date":"20160909","location":"Mars"},
"2":{"name":"Xman","date":"20160909","location":"Galaxy"},
"3":{"name":"Batman","date":"20160909","location":"Earth"}
}
```

Comment: Where you are adding `jsObjRequest` to Volley Request Queue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your `Json Object` to `Request Queue` at the end after `Error Listener`.

```
     JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply get data from JSON, parse it:

```
TextView mTxtDisplay;
String url = "http://192.168.1.102/web_service/test.php/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //parse your responce with JSON object
                JSONObject object     = new JSONObject(response);
                //get JSON object "1" (I'm only doing for 1)
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject("1");
                mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + jsonObject.getString("name"));
            }
        }, 
new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(your_class_context);
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
}
```